# Rails - strip key from array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes I'm submitting in a form.  I'm pre-pending a unique key to the beginning because the names of the fields are the same and I needed to stop them over-writing each other.  But when I save the data serialized in a field, I don't need the key anymore, so I'm looking for the best way to take it out:

```
{"6"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "7"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "8"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "9"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "10"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "11"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "13"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "14"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "16"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "17"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "19"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"}}
```

How can I remove the keys so I have this?

```
{{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 {"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 {"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 {"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 {"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 {"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 {"Wires to GND"=>"0"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over them with `map` and leave out the key.

```
old = {"6"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"}, "7"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"}}
new = old.map { |k,v| v }
```

Comment: I originally tried that, but I got an Array in return and wouldn't allow me to save the data serialized: "Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a Array."  Is there a way to keep it a hash?

Comment: You cannot have a hash with duplicate keys

Comment: @Iceman I believe hash has a values method that will get you the same result as what you have?

Comment: @user3334690 Yeah, you're right of course. Sometimes one overlooks the obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

It's been already answered, but I believe a better solution would be to use `#values`

```
hash = {
 "6"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"},
 "7"=>{"Wires to GND"=>"0"},
 "8"=>{"Between Wires"=>"0"}
}

hash.values
```